# Samsung bootloader unlock but failed to flash custom rom

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, custom-roms, bootloader, android-10

I go to `Settings` > `About Phone` > `Software Information` then tap the `Build number` 7 times to enable Developer Options.

Then I connected my device to the internet and go to `Settings` > `Developer Options` > `OEM Unlocking` set to `Enabled` to unlock the `Bootloader`, *(the phone is reset to data factory but the OEM Unlocked says it's already enabled after that)*.

Now I want to flash a custom ROM, but I failed to do so and the error in download mode says `Only official binaries are allowed to be flashed`. I think this is somehow related to Bootloader which is not fully unlocked. Is there anything I should do before flashing custom ROM?

I'm actually trying to root my device and I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1GLt4pSr-s&ab_channel=PakTech) tutorial.

**DEVICE INFORMATION:**

```
Samsung Galaxy J6 (2018)
SM-J600G/DS
Android 10
Android Patch is Feb. 1, 2021
```

Comment: you did not unlock bootloader. read about vaultkeeper

Comment: I tried searching for it and found this link https://www.droidwin.com/unlock-bootloader-samsung/?unapproved=2229&moderation-hash=f5a4b539c0c1163dde393659e2bf8608#comment-2229

I followed the procedure but I'm lost at STEP 4, where I need to long-press the Volume up, there's no such an option.  Only the `PRESS VOLUME UP to Continue` and `VOLUME DOWN to Continue`. Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Volume Up and proceed with step 5. in case OEM Unlock is missing, also read about RMM protection. if OEM Unlock is enabled device is ready to flash custom binary

Comment: @alecxs - I mean, Only the `PRESS VOLUME UP to Continue` and `VOLUME DOWN to cancel (Restart phone)`, I tried pressing the volume up and just proceed to the download option while it is waiting for the ROM to be flash. I did nothing after that, I tried to reboot and set up the device since it has been reset to factory data, I enabled the developer options, check if the OEM is grey out or exist. It does exist, however, its not grey out.

Comment: Also, from the download option, there was a quote `OEM Lock: OFF` (something like that).

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Same issue, nothing new. From the link above, it says `the OEM unlocking toggle is turned on and is greyed out as well.` that's when the bootloader is surely unlocked. In my case, it doesn't grey out and can be turned off/on. I'm lost at step 4, after booting to Download Mode, there should be an option where I can unlock the bootloader again `(Hold volume up to unlock bootloader)`. This one is mising.

Comment: I'm still searching for a solution, maybe I need to install the old version of android and retry the unlock the bootloader. But it doesn't make any sense, something is missing.

Comment: After finishing the initial setup, the `OEM Unlocking Toggle` is already `Enabled`. I'll try searching for `KG` or `RMM`.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/bounty-fix-for-persistent-rmm-state-lock-after-7-days.3886716